# Convergence of 1/$b_{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My question is the following:  Assume a sequence $b_{n}$ which converge.
Does a limit for $\frac{1}{b_{n}}$ exist?

My idea ist to use the "Quotient Law for Convergent Sequences" by setting: $a_{n}=1$ and just apply the law. But this sounds a little bit to cheap..

Comment: You need that $b_n$ does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't follow. Take $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{b_{n}}= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: Yep. $\frac{1}{b_n} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}} = n$, so $\lim \frac{1}{b_n} = \lim n = \infty$.